# Parsley.js - Understanding and erroring on groups

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I think I've misunderstood the use of groups in Parsley.js. What I had assumed is that groups could be used to not show an error on an individual input but on a group.

For instance, I have three sort code fields for a bank details form.. they're all required, but I don't want each one individually to get an error message (as they're inline), if any of them error, I want the group to get the error message and error class.

Is this possible without writing custom javascript to parse the form data manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `data-parsley-group`. Groups were created in order to validate a multi-step form. That is norrmally a large form that you split into steps (groups) and validate them one at a time.

What you can use, without adding custom javascript, is [`data-parsley-errors-container`](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-for-field).

You should apply this attribute on every field where you want to group the error messages. You should use something like this:

```
data-parsley-errors-container="#element"
```

Where `element` is the id of the element where the messages will be displayed.

Here is an example on how you should create your form ([**jsfiddle available**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/h2n7fph6/)):

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" id="myForm">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-3" id="field1" required
            placeholder="Field 1" data-parsley-errors-container="#listFieldError" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-3" id="field2" required
            placeholder="Field 2" data-parsley-errors-container="#listFieldError" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-3" id="field3" required
            placeholder="Field 3" data-parsley-errors-container="#listFieldError" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="listFieldError"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah, seems I've discovered this through trial and error. Could do with some better documentation. The issue with the above is that I want each field to be required and have digits validation, but only show the error once within the 'group'. I am using the errors container to put the errors in the correct container, but yeah you get duplicated errors and when the errors don't state which field they're relating to it gets a bit ugly.

Comment: If you want only one error for all the fields in the "group" (that is, the `required` message will only appear once), it is possible, but you'll need to do that with some javascript. I can provide an example if you like.

Comment: Using javascript is fine :) I just didn't know if anything like this was built in. Currently doing some other 'group' validation, i.e. a group of fields values musn't be larger than 100, seems over complicated at the moment, can't decide to use events and addError, or my own custom validator rules